# missing xticks when using python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have csv as below
[image]
and then I plot the graph with 'df.plot' with the x-axis as column 0 and y-axis as column 1, 2, 3
my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', header = None)
plt.yscale('log')
df.plot(x=0, y=[1, 2, 3])
```

I get the below graph, not sure why xticks has much less frequency. (only '0', '41-50', '91-100', '141-150', '191-200' are shown.  missing '1-10', '11-20', '21-30'.....)
[image]
Does anyone know how to show all the xticks?

Comment: BTW, what's the relationship with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104067? Why they are exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try plotting x axis labels with [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

```py
plt.xticks(ticks=range(len(df[0])), labels=df[0], rotation=45)
```

[image]

Comment: @Yiann **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.